# Codeblocks compile different my program than gcc in comand

Tags: c

I was trying today to check an Answer and I realized that if i use codeblocks (with gcc) i have to treat the error different from the command line (Ubuntu Linux) using gcc.

The program is like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void){
    double len,x,y =0;
    int n=123456;

    len=floor(log10(abs(n))) + 1;

    x = n / pow(10, len / 2);
    y = n - x * pow(10, len / 2);

    printf("First Half = %f",x);
    printf("\nSecond Half = %f",y);

    return 0;
}
```

And if i try to compile it i get:

> error: implicit declaration of function ‘abs’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]|

So here is the funny thing. I added -lm to the  Compiler => global compiler => settings => Other settings, but the result is the same.

It is working only if i include **stdlib.h**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void){
    double len,x,y =0;
    int n=123456;

    len=floor(log10(abs(n))) + 1;

    x = n / pow(10, len / 2);
    y = n - x * pow(10, len / 2);

    printf("First Half = %f",x);
    printf("\nSecond Half = %f",y);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I use command line (in terminal) using the comand:

```
   gcc program.c -o program -lm
```

The program compiled successfully.

My question: Why happens this ?
I did a research on interent and found that some people says the abs function is declared in **stdlib.h**, not **math.h**. but if i compile in command line (without including stdlib.h) with **-lm** works. I'm confused.

Comment: Look at the command line in CodeBlocks that it does for each file.  It shows this in the build log.

Compare that to the command line you are using outside codeblocks.

Comment: @B. Nadolson please explain...

Comment: At the bottom window, there is a series of tabs like "Search Results", "Build log", "Build messages" .... each source file it says something like gcc -Winline -W -fexceptions -g -lld -D_DEBUG myfile.c -o myfile.o as it compiles each file.

Comment: @ B. Nadolson i think that if there was such option like that, i disable it. I have onliy: "code::blocks, code::blocks debug, search result, build log, build messages, and debugger".

Comment: Note that `abs()` is an integer function; it takes an `int` argument and returns and `int`.  Did you want `fabs()` instead?

Comment: " i think that if there was such option like that, i disable it" --- Click (File-Edit-View top menu ...) Click View->Logs and the window should show.  With Ubuntu you might have to hover over the title bar for the menu to show.

Comment: This code does not own myself, i was just trying to compile it and i noticed that in codeblocks wont compile

Comment: if there is someone who use CodeBlocks, please try my first code (without using stdlib) and explain. Like i say...i'm confused.
Logs says the same thing: "error: implicit declaration of function ‘abs’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]|"

Comment: If CodeBlocks is adding --std=c11 to the compile command line, implicit function declaration is NOT allowed and produces an error.  But from the command line, you aren't using that option so it's just a warning.  This is the reason why including the stdlib.h header gets rid of the error in CodeBlocks.

Comment: So you are saying that abs Function belongs to math.h ? becouse if i not use -lm in gcc option (without including stdlib.h) my program will not compile.

Comment: **AGAIN JUST FOR YOU** ... a header is **not** a library. `abs()` is declared in `stdlib.h`, and with the GNU C library, the actual code happens to be found in `libm.so`.

Comment: I just found the same answer on Internet. Thank  you.

Comment: Ok, finally enough repetition :) Then just adding a bit of advise: Linux and GNU are not all in the world and you'll have to be careful in general where to find *declarations* and *implementations* of functions, e.g., on both Linux and FreeBSD, `dlopen()` is declared in `dlfcn.h`, but the implementation is found in `libc` (automatically linked) for FreeBSD and in `libdl` (needing explicit `-ldl`) for Linux.

Comment: I am not using windows for long time (more then 10 years) so i do know that there things are different than Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Try

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o program -lm
```

or

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o program -lm
```

to make it fail on warnings as Codeblocks seems to do.

Long answer: Linking to a library is a completely different matter than including a header file. In C, for historic reasons, it is "allowed" to use a function that is *not* declared. The compiler in this case assumes a function returning `int` and taking whatever arguments you give it. For `abs()`, these assumptions hold. So later, the linker finds the function when linking with `libm` and everything is fine.

But there are quite some catches: First you will miss simple *typos* if you don't enable warnings. Second, the compiler is unable to check the arguments you give -> crashing program ahead.  And even more problems are to expect if the function does return something other than `int`.

`abs()` is declared in `stdlib.h`. To use it, include this header. And *always* enable compiler warnings (Codeblocks obviously does it for you).

Comment: i compile (both codeblocks and from command line) allways with this "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion --std=c11 -Og". You say that abs is declared in stdlib.h, why i can compile the program in command line using -lm without including stdlib.h?

Comment: This contradicts your question: "if I use command line (in terminal) using the comand: `gcc program.c -o program -lm` The program compiled successfully." -- I don't see any warning flags here. Why this code is acceptable is explained in my answer. There was a time when C didn't even *have* prototypes, so it was reasonable that declarations of functions could be omitted.

Comment: probably i was not clear, codeblocks will not compile without including stdlib.h but in command line (without stdlib.h)  by adding -lm it will. If you use CodeBlocks, please try the first code and explain that.

Comment: probably you didn't read my answer carefully? Or is it just about `-Werror`? this turns all warnings into errors, so compilation stops. And **again** .. `-lm` has nothing to do with it, that's for linking the library (after the compiler did its work). Without it, you'd get an "unresolved symbol" error from the linker.

Comment: Sir are you using GCC ? It is possible that this happens because i use Linux and you probably not?  you are not helping me at all.
If i don't include -lm in command line it will not compile my program with or without stdlib.h. Hope i made my self clear. "gcc program.c -o program
/tmp/ccxOJHWB.o: In function `main':
program.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `log10'
program.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `floor'
program.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `pow'
program.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

Comment: Sorry my bad, i was reading but your answer wasn't 100% ok for me becouse i can compile the program using -lm (math.h) without needing og stdlib.h....or i missing something in here, Thank you for your help.